# JNI call c++ dll occured 'UnsatisfiedLinkError: Invalid access to memory location'

Tags: c++, dll, java-native-interface

I want to call my C++ dll with JNI in my java project. But there is a weird error :  'UnsatisfiedLinkError: Invalid access to memory location'. And my enviroment is: Windows xp sp3, jdk 1.7.0_01 (and jdk 1.6.23), vistual studio 2010. But I do it in win7(64bit)( with the same project and the same jdk & vs2010 ) there is no error.
I used dependcy walker to check the dll and there is no dependcy error. So I'm very puzzled. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the JDK?

Comment: Yes, I have restalled the two version of JDK but it was not avaiable either.

Comment: This is clearly an issue with your Java. Check if you have all necessary requirements installed, you have all patches and you install 32-bit version of JDK. Try running it on a clean XP SP3 installation.

Comment: The JDK I uesd is 32-bit version. And I have installed all the patches I could, but the reslut is the same error. :(

Comment: Would you post your DllMain code?

Comment: Is your DLL 32-bit or 64-bit?  Is your JDK 32-bit on both systems?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are trying to use the same DLL in both environments?  If that is the case, your DLL must be compiled as a 32-bit DLL and you must use a 32-bit JVM on Win7-64.  You may wish to consider shipping both a 32 and 64-bit version of your java application and loading the appropriate library dynamically.  If you are sure that you do not have a 32/64-bit conflict, please provide more information about what and how things are failing.